# How to paste Print Screen on MS Paint automatically when press "PrtSc" button?

Tags: windows, print-screen, microsoft-paint

Same question as by this person, but I need a better answer :)
Paint is great for my needs; I do not need anything else 99% of the time.

How to paste Print Screen on MS Paint automatically when press "PrtSc" button?
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071218032823AAmxWTu

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7.

**EDIT:** The following Auto Hot Key script worked for me:

```
~Printscreen::
!~Printscreen::
IfWinExist Untitled - Paint
{
    WinActivate, Untitled - Paint
    WinWaitActive, Untitled - Paint
}
else
{
    Run Mspaint
    Sleep 10
    WinActivate, Untitled - Paint
    WinWaitActive, Untitled - Paint
}

{
   Send ^v
   Send ^+x
   return
}
```

Comment: Please post your question, rather than expecting folks to go to some other site to read the details.

Comment: Just as an FYI for another option. I do a lot of screenshots at work, and I love this tool for quickly editing, highlighting, and annotating my captures before sending them off: http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) with the following script:

```
; print screen pastes into MS Paint
~Printscreen::
Run Mspaint
WinWaitActive, Untitled - Paint
{
   Send ^v
}
```

I tested this from Vista Business 64-bit with success, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: WORKS PERFECTLY! Would you kindly add an entry for Alt-Prt Scr as well? I have not used this tool before.

Comment: add !~Printscreen:: under ~Printscreen::

Comment: Glad to be of help. AutoHotKey is such an immensely powerful program... I am completely wasting its potential as my main use is just some simple text expansions.  ;)

Comment: It is very cool! Please see my follow-up question: http://superuser.com/questions/214697/how-to-configure-mspaint-on-windows-server-2008r2-win-7-to-start-up-with-1-pixel

Comment: Since @Fantomas doesn't make it clear: the above link leads to a solution that also auto-crops the pasted image in Paint.

Comment: When pressing Print Screen button Paint opens but there is no any image inside, also hotkey works only once, if I press Print Screen for second time Paint doesn't open. Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You might look into the Snipping Tool baked into Windows - it has the added bonus of not needing you to take full screen/window captures if you don't want.  It's not really any more clicks than opening Paint manually but I feel it's much more convenient.

Comment: Thanks, although `Alt-PrtScr` copies just the current Window as well.

Comment: @Fantomas - Right, but my point is Snipping Tool doesn't limit you to that functionality.  You can capture as little or as much of the screen as you want.

Answer (score 2):

I believe CTRL+V ***would*** be the best method, which will paste the screen into MS Paint.

Comment: Lol, this answer made my day!

Comment: +1 As this answer is better than the question.

Comment: Apologies, I was in a rush when I answered. I've highlighted the word "would", as it actually changes my answer to what I meant to say, rather than it seeming like I didn't RTFQ! I believe that CTRL+V is a very simple solution that fits what your asking. I mean, Authotkey is a great solution from mpeterson, but one mouse-click versus two key strokes, we're splitting hairs saying one is faster than the other.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing/). If Print_Screen + MS Paint it's all you need, then Jing will make whatever you are doing even easier.

Answer (score -1):

How about opening a small paint window or even returning to previous window automatically?
Or maybe it's possible to paste print screen into MS paint without switching windows?