# How to configure mspaint on Windows Server 2008R2/ Win 7 to start up with 1-pixel canvas or auto-crop a pasted image?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, microsoft-paint

I do a lot of screen print capturing, and I have just figured out how to use `AutoHotKey` to paste screen prints into MsPaint automatically.

[How to paste Print Screen on MS Paint automatically when press "PrtSc" button?](https://superuser.com/questions/214229/how-to-paste-print-screen-on-ms-paint-automatically-when-press-prtsc-button)

However, one small problem I have is that ... if I grabbed a screen with `Alt-Prt Scr` that is only 50x50 pixels, then there would be extra white margin around it, because MSPaint starts out with a larger canvas by default. How can I make it ALWAYS start with 1x1 instead?

Comment: To customize: locate the AutoHotKey icon, right- or left-click it and look for options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the script slightly to auto-crop the image.

```
; print screen pastes into MS-Paint
~Printscreen::
!~Printscreen::
Run Mspaint
WinActivate, Untitled - Paint
WinWaitActive, Untitled - Paint
{
   Send ^v
   Send ^+x
}
```

(so now it pastes the image, and then crops it)

Comment: Unfortunatelly this does not work with newest Paint (one that has the ribbon). I am not sure what the command for auto-crop is.

Comment: I think these edits will work. I tested it on my Windows 7 64-bit box, and it works. (I also added a line to activate the MSPaint, as when I tried alt-prtscrn I had to manually activate it for some reason)

Comment: How do I make sure that AutoHotkey starts up automatically every time the computer boots?

Comment: I would just drop a shortcut of AutoHotKey into the Startup folder, which is Method Two on this site. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1401-startup-programs-change.html