# Macro in Windows 7 - Open Paint in Edit Mode

Tags: windows-7, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to paste Print Screen on MS Paint automatically when press “PrtSc” button?](https://superuser.com/questions/214229/how-to-paste-print-screen-on-ms-paint-automatically-when-press-prtsc-button)

Want to create a simple Windows 7 macro to open paint in edit mode. I frequently take screenshots and need to quickly crop or markup the picture.

Use: print screen button + macro command + ctrl v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) would be your best bet. You could design a macro to do all three steps with a single key combo. It's free, open source and (in my opinion) easy to use.

**EDIT: See the script in the answer to the question Karan linked to**